# Why do plots change in dependence on sample order?

Tags: cluster-analysis, testing-and-verification

I suggest two identical data set dat1 and dat2, save the order
of samples is different.

After selecting the first or the second data,
the SCORE and LOADING plots are different.
This seems to be in contrary to the very purpose of PCA analysis.

```
(*two identical datasets, save the order of samples*)
dat1 = {{2, 4, 1, 3}, {5, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 9, 3, 4}};
dat2 = {{5, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 9, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 1, 3}};
dima = Dimensions[dat1][[1]];
(*selector of the data: either dat1 or dat2*)
dat = dat1;
(*whitening*)
meanD = N[Sum[dat[[i]], {i, 1, dima}]/dima];
dat = Table[dat[[i]] - meanD, {i, 1, dima}];
(*indexes to select first and second principle components*)
C1 = 1;
C2 = 2;
(*SCORE PLOT*)
PrCmp = PrincipalComponents[dat, Method -> "Covariance"];
Dcv = Table[{i, PrCmp[[C1, i]], PrCmp[[C2, i]]}, {i, 1, dima}];
Gcv = ListPlot[Flatten[List /@ Dcv[[All, {2, 3}]], 1], 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 150, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.02]}, 
   Axes -> {True, True}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Principle Component 1", "Principle Component 2"}];
(*updating the score plot with numbers of positions where spectra \
where taken*)
vs = 0.1; (*lables vertical shift*)
lb1 = Text[#[[1]], {1.05 #[[{2, 3}]][[1]], 
     1.0 #[[{2, 3}]][[2]] + vs}] & /@ Dcv;
(*LOADING PLOT*)
covarM = dat.Transpose[dat];
eigenS = Eigensystem[covarM];
Dpc = Table[{i, eigenS[[2, C1, i]], eigenS[[2, C2, i]]}, {i, 1, 
    dima}]; 
Gcp = ListPlot[Flatten[List /@ Dpc[[All, {2, 3}]], 1], 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 150, 
   PlotStyle -> {Darker[Red], PointSize[0.02]}, Axes -> {True, True}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Principle Component 1", "Principle Component 2"}];
(*to add the connecting lines*)
Dpcl = Table[{eigenS[[2, C1, i]], eigenS[[2, C2, i]]}, {i, 1, dima}];
(*updating the loading plot with numbers of positions where spectra \
where taken*)
vs = 0.1 ;(*lables vertical shift*)
lb3 = Text[#[[1]], {1.05 #[[{2, 3}]][[1]], 
     1.0 #[[{2, 3}]][[2]] + vs}] & /@ Dpc;
G03l = ListLinePlot[Table[{{0, 0}, Dpcl[[i]]}, {i, 1, dima}], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];
{G01 = Show[Gcv, Graphics[{Black, lb1}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], 
 G03 = Show[Gcp, Graphics[{Black, lb3}], G03l, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]}
```